# Flutter how to get context outside builder function for showDialog

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Im making an app where I fetch data from a firestore base and I want to show an Alertdialog that asks for confirmation. But I cant get the context from the build function in my 'buildPokemon' function. Is there a better/easier way to do this?

[image]

```html
class _PokedexState extends State<Pokedex> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pokédex'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        leading: const Icon(MdiIcons.pokeball),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: readPokemon(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Couldn\u0027t find any Pokémon :( ');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final users = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView(
              children: users.map(buildPokemon).toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddPokemonPage()));
        },
        label: const Text('Add Pokémon'),
        icon: new Icon(MdiIcons.pokemonGo),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildPokemon(Pokemon pokemon) => (
Card(
  elevation: 4.0,
  child:Column(
    children: [
      ListTile(
        title: Text(pokemon.name),
        subtitle: Text(pokemon.size),
        trailing:IconButton(onPressed: (){
          showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog());
          DocumentReference docuRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Pokemon').doc(pokemon.id);
          docuRef.delete();
        }, icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))
      ),

    ],
  ),
)
  );
```

Comment: +1 for using a tearoff currently, but you will need to then change your map to `map((e)=>buildPokemon(e, context))`